# Visual Studio 2017 doesn't install dependencies automatically when adding a package to a .NET Core application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

When I'm trying to add any Nuget package with dependencies my VS2017 doesn't automatically install those dependencies, asking me to install them manually:

*Install/reference Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering 2.2.0 directly to project*

It is Asp.Net Core 2.1 Web Api application.

Edit:
I tried to clear Nuget cache and it helped with majority of packages, but not all:
VS2017 > Tools > Options > NuGet Package Manager > General > Clear All NuGet Cache(s)

Comment: What's your exact step by step process of adding the nuget package?

Comment: Maybe also say **WHICH** package you were trying to install

Comment: I used Manage NuGet packages window in VS2017 and tried to add Microsoft.AspNetCore v2.2.0 package.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering 2.2.0` could be referenced only in `Asp.Net Core 2.2`.

Try to reference `Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering 2.1.x`

Comment: Yes, this was a following problem I had after all dependencies were installed or at least NuGet attempted to install them. Before I cleared NuGet cache I had to walk through dependency chain and install each dependency manually.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the solution to fix auto dependency install was to clear NuGet cache: VS2017 > Tools > Options > NuGet Package Manager > General > Clear All NuGet Cache(s)

After dependencies were installed I had different unrelated problem with Microsoft.AspNetCore v2.2.0 compatability